# Cannot read property 'join' of undefined in Javascript file Electron JS

Tags: python, html, electron

I have an application in Electron JS that is calling a python function to execute a python script.
When the script executes it should send the data back to the Electron JS GUI and display it.

The issue I am having is that it is saying that join is undefined:

> weather.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of
>   undefined
>       at get_weather (weather.js:9)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (weather.html:14)

here is my JavaScript file:

```
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')
var path = require("path")

function get_weather() {

  var city = document.getElementById("city").value

  var options = {
    scriptPath : path.join(__dirname, '/../engine/'),
    args : [city]
  }

  let pyshell = new PythonShell('weatherApp.py', options);


  pyshell.on('message', function(message) {
    swal(message);
  })
  document.getElementById("city").value = "";
}
```

The line "scriptPath : path.join(__dirname, '/../engine/')," seems to be the offending piece of code.

My gui.html file is as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Get your local weather ...</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Enter city name here: <label>
    <input id="city" type = "text" placeholder="City">
    <button type = "button" value="clickme" onclick="get_weather()">Get Weather</button>
    <!--- <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="get_weather();">Go!</button> -->
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <script src="/home/ironmantis7x/Documents/BSSLLC/projects/node_electron/electronDemoApps/guiApp/gui/linkers/weather.js"></script>
    <p><button type="button"><a href="gui.html">Back to Main Page</a></button>

  </body>
</html>
```

What error(s) do I need to fix to get this working correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you running your program? What command are you typing? Also if you pause your debugger inside your function, what is the value of path?

Comment: I am running it from Electron using npm command. It makes a gui window and then I go to a page where I click the button after entering in the city I want weather for

Comment: what electron version are you using? Since electron 5 node integration is not enabled in the renderer process per default. You may want to use a preload script. Also do you use webpack or something else before running your code?

Comment: electron version = v5.0.6. Is there a way to enable the renderer process by default? I do not use webpack or anything else before running my code. I just type "npm start" at the terminal and it runs my app. Is there something else I should do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The Problem**

Since Electron 5 `nodeIntegration` is disabled by default in the window. Since normal browser API does not know `require` or `join`, you get errors when you try.

**Reenabling nodeIntegration**

You could enable `nodeIntegration` again, but it was disabled for a reason. Be sure you read and understand the [electron security tutorial](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content).

**Using a preload script**

Another way is to use a preload script. Let's have a look at the `BrowserWindow` [documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions).

When creating a new BrowserWindow you can add several options. For this case we need the `webPreferences.preload` option:

> Specifies a script that will be loaded before other scripts run in the page. This script will always have access to node APIs no matter whether node integration is turned on or off. The value should be the absolute file path to the script. When node integration is turned off, the preload script can reintroduce Node global symbols back to the global scope.

Be aware that the preload script is run in the renderer process.

**Example**

Following is an example app, that opens a window with a button that uses the electron `dialog` to select files. This would not work with disabled `nodeIntegration` but thanks to our preload script, we reintroduced `dialog.showOpenDialog()` to our window.

*main.js*

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const { join } = require("path");

let win;

app.on("ready", () => {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      //this is the default since electron 5
      nodeIntegration: false,
      //here you load your preload script
      preload: join(__dirname, "preload.js")
    }
  });

  win.loadURL(join(__dirname, "index.html"));
});
```

*preload.js*

```js
const { dialog } = require("electron").remote;

window.mystuff = {
  selectFile
};

async function selectFile() {
  const files = await dialog.showOpenDialog({
    properties: ["openFile", "multiSelections"]
  });

  return files;
}
```

*index.html*

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <main>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">select file</button>
      <ul id="foo"></ul>
    </main>
    <script>
      async function myFunction() {
        //the function provided by the preload script
        const files = await window.mystuff.selectFile();

        const list = document.getElementById("foo");

        for (const file of files) {
          const node = document.createElement("LI");
          const textNode = document.createTextNode(file);
          node.appendChild(textNode);
          list.appendChild(node);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Sending events via IPC**

If you are unsure your functionality should be exposed in the window, you can also send events via `ipcRenderer`.

*preload.js*

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");


window.mystuff = {
  selectFile
};


function selectFile() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    ipcRenderer.on("selected-files", (e, files) => {
      resolve(files);
    });

    ipcRenderer.send("select-files");
  });
}
```

Additional part in *main.js*

```js
ipcMain.on("select-files", async () => {
  const files = await dialog.showOpenDialog({
    properties: ["openFile", "multiSelections"]
  });

  win.webContents.send("selected-files", files);
});
```