# Is there a way of calling the Electron's element in HTML

Tags: electron

I wanted to use electron's element in HTML file so that when the URL is hit, I can get the data from web page and user details of the webpage.

var uName= username.sync() returns me in main.js. How to make use of the username that I have got or how can I make use of uName?
Note: have tried IPC and it did not work out. 
main.js:-

```
    const username = require('username');
    var uName=username.sync();
    global.sendUName = function(uName){
        return uName;
    }
```

Can we use the same in index.html? I used the below code and it gave me require is undefined, later I fixed it using browserify.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script> let {remote} = require('electron');
 const hello = remote.getGlobal("sendUName")();
 document.write(hello);
 </head>
 </html>
```

Comment: IPC is indeed one option to use modules that only work in the main process, but without your code we have no chance to know why it didn't work for you. Maybe other answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57823900/4945892) will give you an idea where to go. If not, please add more information to your question by editing it.

Comment: @Rhayene: I have added the code. I thought I can use require.js as using require in html is a problem. But even that didn't work out. highly appreciated if you could assist :)

Comment: Require won't work per default in the renderer process if you use electron 5 or higher, because the new default is disabled node integration for security reasons. Since `require` is part of the node API, it won't work out of the box. So here my additional question: what electron version do you use?

Comment: @Rhayene I use Electron V6.0.9 . Now I get it, I used require.js node module to access Electron elements in HTML as well.

Comment: @Rhayene IS there any other way that I can use the ELectron elements in HTML?