# How to recieve WebContent events from static page on Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

Hello so i am new with Electron and trying to capture event from my index.js into my index.html, but i cannot make it to work.

My index.js code is below

```
const electron = require('electron')
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, ipcMain, Tray, dialog, shell }  = electron

app.on('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    minWidth: 750, minHeight: 250, width: 820, height: 550,
    icon: __dirname + '/favicon.ico', maximizable: true, resizable: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
    }
  })
  win.setMenu(null);        
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)

  var rows = { FirstName: 'John Doe' }
  result.then(function(rows) {
    win.webContents.send("resultSent", rows);
    console.log(rows);             
  });
```

While on my index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Customer Management System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Home</h1>

    <div id="result"></div>

    <script type="module">
        const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron")
        ipcRenderer.on("resultSent", function (event, data) {
            console.log("received data", data)
            alert("received data")
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when i open the electron devTool is returns below error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Comment: well, you explicitly set `nodeIntegration: false`. Thus, you won't have access to node api in your html (that is `require` is not defined). Read up the [`BrowserWindow constructor`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) docs

Comment: I wrote an answer for a similar question - maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57823900/4945892