# IPC in electron renderer throws error from missing function __dirname

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron, ipc

I wanted to use the following code to send a message from the renderer to the main process, which then writes it to a log file using electron-log. My main.js looks like this:

```js
import { app, protocol, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
import { createProtocol } from 'vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib'
import installExtension, { VUEJS_DEVTOOLS } from 'electron-devtools-installer'
const { ipcMain } = require('electron');
const log = require('electron-log');
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

// Scheme must be registered before the app is ready
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
  { scheme: 'app', privileges: { secure: true, standard: true } }
])

async function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    frame: true,
    width: 400,
    height: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      enableRemoteModule: false
    }
  })

  ipcMain.on('infoLog', (event, args) => {
    log.info(args)
   });
....
```

Now I tried to address the IPC in my App.vue accordingly:

```js
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar'
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Navbar
  },
  created: function () {
    ipcRenderer.send('infoLog','A async message to main')
  }
}
```

When I start it with `yarn electron:serve` I see this error in the console of the window:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/electron/index.js:4)
    at Object../node_modules/electron/index.js (chunk-vendors.js:2778)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/index.js?!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js:5)
    at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/index.js?!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (app.js:938)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js:2)
    at Module../src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (app.js:1099)
```

What I don't understand is that I set it up exactly like Electron's doc:

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main

Comment: Make your `nodeIntegration: true` and it should work.

Also read and understand about `nodeIntegration`, context isolation, and the security issues when using nodeIntegration.

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4362

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 different issues here:

- the correct webpack configuration to support node.js code
- missing node integration to use node API like `require`

The stacktrace you are seeing here likely comes from an incorrect webpack configuration. Unless told otherwise, webpack tries to replace `__dirname` with something different. Here we don't want that - node provides `__dirname` and we want to use it, so we have to tell webpack to leave `__dirname` alone.

You'll find an example in the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/).

For webpack 5 adding a node section should help:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  node: {
    global: false,
    __filename: false,
    __dirname: false,
  }
};
```

After you solved this problem you'll likely fall over the issue that your browser window does not know `require`. You can reintroduce specific node API  like the IPC by using a preload script. Don't activate the full node integration without knowing what you are doing.

For an example, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57823900/4945892).