# Systeminformation is only pending and doesn't show any results in vue

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron, system-information

As my personal project I want to make a desktop app with the use of Electron and Vue. I've got that all set up and running flawlessly with already finished gui, but there is one small problem. To get the system info I'm using [systeminformation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation) and calling it in the script tag of my General.vue file doesn't work.

**General.js**

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import systeminformation from 'systeminformation'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'General',
  mounted () {
    this.getData() // Call the function once started
  },
  methods: {
    getData: function () {
      console.log('test 1') // Gets printed out
      systeminformation.cpu()
        .then(data => console.log(data)) // All of these do nothing
        .catch(reason => console.log(reason))
        .finally(() => console.log('test 1.5'))
      console.log('test 2') // Gets printed out
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

This code is supposed to get all the information about the CPU of my device, but nothing is showing up in the console except for the tests. I've tried running it in a simple test project with just basic Node and it works just as it's supposed to be.

My only theory as to why it's not working here is perhaps that it's in .vue and too far away from the backend part of the app? I will be very grateful for any help. If you want to experiment, here's a [link](https://github.com/FeedTheMEe/specsie) to the project for you to clone it.

Comment: I don't know this library, but if this library requires node APIs to work (from what it does this is very likely), you may need to run this in a preload script. since you don't have node.js API available in the renderer process. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57823900/4945892) to get an idea how to use a preload script (it is a bit older, the BrowserWindow API may look a little bit different in the newest electron version). In the preload script you will have access to the full Node API including the [os module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/os.html).

Comment: @Rhayene Thank you a lot, I have no idea how did I forget about these. It works, but there is an another catch. It works only when I set nodeIntegration to true, which I don't want to do in the final product 'cause of the security issues. I've searched far and wide and I just cannot figure out how to make it work.. The error that I'm getting now is from webpack, telling me that "__dirname is not defined". Can't find a way to solve it other than enabling nodeIntegration to true, which I don't want to of course. Tried many different ways, none of them work =c

Comment: would you mind to add your preload script, main script and webpack configuration to the question? I don't see webpack in the linked project so this seems a bit outdated. Also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65469242/4945892)

Comment: with main script I mean the electron script where you open the BrowserWindow in the main process ^^