# Cannot read property 'require' of undefined

Tags: electron

I am creating an application to use mysql. I want to call a function from the main.js file. This main.js file is the main application file, just like the documentation. I saw an example of how to call this function:

```
const { remote } = require('electron');
const main = remote.require('./main');
main.saveUser();
```

But it gives the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'require' of undefined at app.js:4'
```

I believe it has updated and the way of calling has changed, can someone help me by sending the link to the documentation that talks about, please.

Comment: In your error it says that you run this code in the renderer process (is this what you wanted to do?) - you don't have node integration in your renderer process by default. This answer may help you further solving this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57823900/4945892

Answer (score 4):

Solution is very easy. Just add `webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true, enableRemoteModule: true}` in your BrowserWindow in main.js.

The code look like this:

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
   width: 990, 
   height: 660,
   title: "Okkhor52 Tools", 
   resizable: false, 
   frame: false, 
   webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true, 
      enableRemoteModule: true
   }
});
```